# Showing that $U(1)_R$ charge is non-anomalous in SUSY QCD when $r=\frac{F-N}{F}$

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, quantum-anomalies

I'm trying to show that the value of the R-charge $r$ for which the R-symmetry is non-anomalous is given by $r=\frac{F-N}{F}$.

To do this we must calculate the triangle diagrams for the quarks $\psi_i$ and the gauginos $\lambda^a$. For the quarks, everything seems right. What I get is that

$$ (r-1)\sum_{i,j,k}^F \langle 0 |T\{ (\bar{\psi}^i\psi^i) (\bar{\psi}^jT^a\psi^j) (\bar{\psi}^kT^b\psi^k )\} |0\rangle = F(r-1)\delta_{ab}$$

where $T_a$ is in the fundamental of the gauge group $SU(N)$. However, when it comes to the triangle diagram for the gauginos I get that

$$\sum_{a,b,c}^{N^2-1} \langle 0 |T\{ (\bar{\lambda}^a\lambda^a) (\bar{\lambda}^bt^A\lambda^b) (\bar{\lambda}^ct^B\lambda^c )\} |0\rangle = (N^2-1)(N)\delta_{AB}$$

where $t^A$ are in the adjoint rep.

**Here is the problem**

The $N^2-1$ should not be there. It came from $tr(I_{N^2-1})$, just like the $F$ came from $tr(I_F)$. This came from the fact that I assumed that the contraction of

$$ \overbrace{\lambda^a \bar{\lambda}^b} = \delta_{ab}. $$

So this must have been incorrect, but why? And what happens to the sums over $a,b,c$ then?

Comment: There is no $(N^2-1)$. $N^2-1$ is just the dimension of the adjoint. You also do not get the dimension of the fundamental, $N$, in the quark contribution. There are many issues with your indices. The generators $t^A$ also carry indices, which you suppress. If you do things properly, you arrive at traces tr$t^At^B$ in the respective representations, which of course gives just the Dynkin indices, $1/2$ for the fundamental and $N$ for the adjoint. Recalling that the the quarks come in conjugate pairs, i.e. you have $F$ generations of $Q+\bar Q$, then gives the correct result.

Comment: Fair enough.. I did suppress the indices of the generators and the things they contract with.. So you're saying that I forgot to sum over the color indices in the quark contribution? Also, what do you mean that there is no $N^2-1$ doesn't the sum over the $a,b,c$ run from 0 to $N^2-1$? I guess I'm wondering why I explicitly write out the flavor sum but not the sum over the $a,b,c$?

Comment: Yes. The indices are very different. The propagators are diagonal in color space, you will get contractions of the form $T^A_{ab}T^B_{bc}\delta_{ca}$.

Comment: Isn't that where the $N\delta_{AB}$ comes from?

Comment: Yes, precisely. But no $N^2-1$.

Comment: I understand that the $N^2-1$ shouldn't be there, but i'm not exactly sure why. All I did was treat the adjoint indices $a,b,c$ the same as the flavor indices. Which of course can be mistaken. But what exactly is the relevant distinction that keeps me from getting the term $tr(I_{N^2-1})$ in the gaugino term?

Comment: If you treat everything the same, there should be either both an $N^2-1$ (# of gluons) and an $2N$ (# of quark and antiquark colors) or neither of them. The calculation shows that it's neither of them. Just draw the diagrams and use the fact that the propagators are diagonal in the color space.

Comment: I believe I see what you're saying.. I'll give it a go in the morning, though.. Thanks!

Comment: @marmot Sleeping on it definitely helped. I realized what you were saying about the indices: There gaugino current should be $\lambda^a t^B_{ac} \lambda^c$.. Then we have a factor of 2 in $2N$. But since we also have an super field with anti quarks we also have to add the contribution due to the conserved current for the anti quarks also. We don't have to do this for the gaugino since its kinetic contribution came from the $W_\alpha W^\alpha$ term, and hence there is only one conserved current. This yields the correct answer.

Comment: oops I meant $\bar{\lambda}^a t^B_{ac} \lambda^c$.